# Grammar for a between operator

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I'm trying to make a ANTLR4 grammar for the following scenario:

```
column < 3.2
column < 5 > 2.2
column > 2 < 5.2
```

So it can be a range or a simple comparison.

This is my grammar file

```
grammar myGrammar;

@parser::members
{
    protected const int EOF = Eof;
}

@lexer::members
{
    protected const int EOF = Eof;
    protected const int HIDDEN = Hidden;
}

/*
 * Parser Rules
 */

prog: expr+ ;

expr : COLUMN LESSTHAN DECIMAL BIGGERTHAN DECIMAL       # range
     | COLUMN BIGGERTHAN DECIMAL LESSTHAN DECIMAL       # inversedRange
     | COLUMN OPERATOR DECIMAL                          # simple
     ;
/*
 * Lexer Rules
 */

COLUMN: ('all')?('columns' | 'otherColumn')
DECIMAL : ([0-9]+.?[0-9]*);
LESSTHAN : ('<'|'<=');
BIGGERTHAN : ('>'|'>=');
OPERATOR : ('<'|'<='|'>'|'>='|'=');
WS
    :   (' ' | '\r' | '\n') -> channel(HIDDEN)
    ;
```

It works only for

```
column < 5.2 > 2
column > 2.2 < 5
```

but it doesn't work for

```
column < 2
```

it says `expecting biggerthan`. It doesn't match the simple comparison

it also doesn't work if the first number is an integer instead of decimal AND if there's no space between the first int and the second operator.

```
column < 2> 2
```

I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`column < 2> 2` doesn't work because the `.` meta char matches any character. So the `>` directly following the `2` gets matched by it. You need to match the literal `.` instead:

```
DECIMAL : [0-9]+ '.'? [0-9]*;
```

`column < 2` doesn't work because the token `OPERATOR` used in your `simple` alternative will only ever match the `=`. All others will be matched by either `LESSTHAN` or `BIGGERTHAN`. This is simply how the lexer works: if 2 or more lexer rules match the same amount of characters, the rule defined first will win.

Try something like this instead:

```
prog : expr+ EOF;

expr : COLUMN LESSTHAN DECIMAL BIGGERTHAN DECIMAL  # range
     | COLUMN BIGGERTHAN DECIMAL LESSTHAN DECIMAL  # inversedRange
     | COLUMN operator DECIMAL                     # simple
     ;

operator : LESSTHAN | BIGGERTHAN | EQUALS;

COLUMN     : 'all'? ('columns' | 'otherColumn')
DECIMAL    : [0-9]+ '.'? [0-9]*;
LESSTHAN   : '<' | '<=';
BIGGERTHAN : '>' | '>=';
EQUALS     : '=';
WS         : [ \r\n\t] -> channel(HIDDEN);
```

Comment: It works like a charm and I even understand why. Thank you sir!

Comment: How would I get the operator value in VisitSimple method in my visitor? Thank you

Comment: Better get the `type` of the token. Something like `context.GetStart().GetType()` which you can compare with `myGrammarLexer.LESSTHAN` (untested!)